# Using linq to check count of IEnumerable list

Tags: c#, list, linq, where-clause, contains

I have a list of type IEnumerable.

In my linq I simply want to say if this list has a count greater than 0 and it's contained in the query then it should only contain results where ref is contained in the list otherwise if count is zero return all.

I am getting the error:

> operator > cannot be applied to operands of type method group and
>   'init'

```
public IEnumerable<int> Workareas { get; set; }

var workareas = trackAnalyticsService.GetWorkareas(new Track.TrackDataFilter(new int[] { companyId }, null, from, to, userFirmRef), maxWorkareas);
```

Comment: What is an *operand error*? Please give the full error message. You probably also want to use `.Any(...)` instead of `.Where(...)` if you just want to know if the list contains any items. Please provide some actual code because what you have shown above cannot possibly be what you have.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (that compiles) with sample data and expected results based on that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

> > operator > cannot be applied to operands of type method group and 'init'

Are you should that last word is "init" and not "int"?  (Int makes more sense).

Presumably, somewhere you have `workareas.Count > 0`.  Except `IEnumerable`s don't have a `Count` property; they have a `Count()` method.  (Since a method can have many overloads when you use a method name without its parameters, it's called a "method group")

So, you want `workareas.Count() > 0`.  But actually, you want `workareas.Any()`  (That will stop looking as soon as it finds one, instead of counting every one).